# How to add assembly code in Linux

Tags: linux, assembly, kernel

I am writing a Linux kernel module on Fedora core 6 and I am wondering if anyone could tell me how to add the assembly code shown below to my program. The assembly code was written for Windows and I have no idea how to convert to Linux kernel program.

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER

unsigned char lookKbits(char k)
{
    _asm {
        mov dl, k
        mov cl, 16
        sub cl, dl
        mov eax, [wordval]
        shr eax, cl
    }
}

unsigned char WORD_hi_lo(char byte_high, char byte_low)
{
    _asm {
        mov ah,byte_high
        mov al,byte_low
    }
}

#endif
```

Comment: your question isn't very clear. And that's inline assembly.

Comment: You should at least give the resulting assembly functions.

Comment: Should I be worried that you want to put a function that builds a WORD result in eax but is declared to return a char into the *kernel*?  Whatever answer you find that compiles should have the generated code carefully inspected for correctness.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to actually port it into working assembly instructions, but it doesn't really make sense.

I also came across this discussion (http://cboard.cprogramming.com/archive/index.php/t-92815.html) which seems to be the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

[GCC Inline Assembly Howto](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html)

If you're just looking for syntax:

> The format of basic inline assembly is
>   very much straight forward. Its basic
>   form is
>
> asm("assembly code");
>
> Example: asm("movl %ecx %eax"); /* moves the contents of ecx to eax */

Specifically, look at [section 3](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#s3), which compares Intel to AT&T syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried writing it in C? To my naive eye it doesn't look like it needs to be in assembler.

Comment: The main idea is that these functions will be called too many times in my program and the program should excute as fast as possible.

Comment: Writing it in C really is a good idea - then you can profile your code and determine whether an assembly version is REALLY required.

Comment: No program needs execute "as fast as possible" - most only need to execute finitely fast - figure out how fast that is and optimise it until you reach it, then stop.

Answer (score 1):

In the kernel, you can also use the `__asm__` macro, for an example see `include/asm/atomic.h`. [LXR](http://lxr.linux.no) is a very good site for browsing and searching through the Linux sourcecode, you will find many examples there.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is how to write inline assembly in gcc.  Section 5.35 of the gcc manual has extensive information about that.  However, for this particular example, you're almost certainly much better off rewriting these functions is C, as you'll probably get better code out of the compiler than what the asm statements produce...